# Irreproducible builds in Android when using AppCompat library

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I was trying to create reproducible Android builds, but blocked by drawable resources from AppCompat library.

The drawables, `abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png` and `abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png` appear and disappear from folders `res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17` and `res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4` in the artifact apk files across different builds against same code base.

I'm using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1` and Gradle 5.4.1, and not directly referencing these resources.

`shrinkResources` wouldn't affect the result as I tested with both `true` and `false`. When it was `true`, I tried to add `keep.xml` to discard or keep these resources, but the results are the same, neither of them were fully removed.

I suspected it was caused by Gradle [merge resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#merge-resources), but couldn't find logs or mapping reports for that.

I noticed that it is Rtl folder that these drawables may be shown, so I also tried `android:supportsRtl="false"`. But the issue persists and rtl resources from AppCompat are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be I have used booster framework in my project, which randomly removed the resources when creating artifact apks.
I've created an issue for them https://github.com/didi/booster/issues/103, and have this question resolved.